# How should I choose the Anchor boxes for YOLOv3 like model for fine tuning it on a custom dataset?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, object-detection, yolo

I have a YOLOv3 inspired network developed in python and Tensorflow which uses 9 anchor boxes (3 anchor boxes for each scale i.e. 3 for large scale output, 3 for middle and 3 for small).

I have already pre trained the model on all classes of COCO dataset using anchors generated by k-means clustering on training data of COCO.

***Question:*** if I want to fine tune this network on only 1 class on my custom data set ..should I use the same anchors of COCO as used while pre-training or should I generate new anchors again by using K-means clustering on my own data set?

Also can i change the number of anchors while fine tuning i.e. can I increase the number of anchors from 9 to 12 (4 anchors per scale)?
Would it affect my model performance since originally it was pretrained on 3 anchors and would increasing the number of anchors specifically on finetune stage be the right thing to do?

***P.S.:*** If someone could explain how important a role does anchor boxes play in the detection, it would be great. Also is there any general method of choosing anchor boxes other than K-means clustering?